# How to find the current location near to one of the location in location-list(Arraylist)?

Tags: android, location, proximity

I would like to find the current location where it is resides in the location list of GPX file. Here i'm having the location arraylist. How to check the current location presence near to one of the arraylist location. do i have to add proximity for all the location presence in location list. or Is there any other way to achieve this? Please help me.